# Prove that there is $v$ that satisfies specific inner product conditions

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

I have question from paper, to prove that for the following conditions over $C$

$(i)$ $[\alpha v,u]=\alpha [v,u]$

$(ii)$ $[v,u]=[u,v]$

there is $v\neq0$ for which not satisfies  $[v,v]\gt0$

if its not understandable, ill try to correct

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics SE. Take a tour: https://math.stackexchange.com/tour.  You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context by stating what you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, etc.; both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult this link for further guidance: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959 .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So over $\mathbb{C}$ the standard inner product satisfies conditions

- $\langle av,w\rangle = a\langle v,w\rangle$ for all $a \in \mathbb{C}$ (i.e. bilinearity in the first factor)
- $\langle v,w\rangle = \overline{\langle v,w\rangle}$ (i.e. its Hermitian).

This Hermitian property is important, and the fact that you have the condition that $[v,w]=[w,v]$ instead means you should look to exploit this somehow.

To do this consider $[ia,ia]$ for some $a \in \mathbb{C}$. Then we have:

$[ia,ia] \stackrel{\text{prop } i)}{=} i[a,ia] \stackrel{\text{prop } ii)}{=} i[ia,a] \stackrel{\text{prop } i)}{=} i^2[a,a] = -[a,a]$.

So just pick any vector $v \in C$, then by the above we must have either $[v,v] \leq 0$ or $[iv,iv] \leq 0 $.